# Generic modals with Redux and Thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I've been looking into creating generic modals with React, Redux, and Thunk. Ideally, my state would look like the following:

```
export interface ConfirmModalState {
  isOpened: boolean;
  onConfirm: null | Function
}

export const initialConfirmModalState: ConfirmModalState = {
  isOpened: false,
  onConfirm: null
};
```

However, this would mean putting non-serializable data into the state, which seems to be highly discouraged.

I've read a [great blogpost](https://hub.packtpub.com/creating-reusable-generic-modals-react-and-redux/) by [markerikson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62937/markerikson). However, I don't think the proposed solution would work with asynchronous actions and Thunk.

How do you suggest to resolve this issue?

Comment: what if you want different modals on different platforms?

Answer (score 10):

I actually wrote the post that you linked, and I wrote a much-expanded version of that post a couple years later:

[Practical Redux, Part 10: Managing Modals and Context Menus](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/07/practical-redux-part-10-managing-modals/).

I've actually implemented a couple variations of this approach myself since I wrote that post, and the best solution I've found is to add a custom middleware that returns a promise when you dispatch a "show modal" action, and resolves the promise with a "return value" when the dialog is closed.

There's an existing implementation of this approach at https://github.com/AKolodeev/redux-promising-modals . I ended up making my own implementation. I have a partial version of my homegrown approach in a gist at https://gist.github.com/markerikson/8cd881db21a7d2a2011de9e317007580 , and the middleware looked roughly like:

```
export const dialogPromiseMiddleware: Middleware<DialogPromiseDispatch> = storeAPI => {
    const dialogPromiseResolvers: Record<string, Resolver> = {};

    return next => (action: AnyAction) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            // Had to resort to `toString()` here due to https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-starter-kit/issues/157
            case showDialogInternal.toString(): {
                next(action);
                let promiseResolve: Resolver;
                const dialogPromise = new Promise((resolve: Resolver) => {
                    promiseResolve = resolve;
                });

                dialogPromiseResolvers[action.payload.id] = promiseResolve!;

                return dialogPromise;
            }
            case closeDialog.toString(): {
                next(action);
                const {id, values} = action.payload;
                const resolver = dialogPromiseResolvers[id];
                if (resolver) {
                    resolver(values);
                }

                delete dialogPromiseResolvers[id];
                break;
            }
            default:
                return next(action);
        }
    };
};
```

(note: I made that gist when I was having some TS syntax issues getting dispatching to work correctly, so it's likely it won't 100% work out of the box. RTK also now includes some `.match()` action matching utilities that would be useful here. but, it shows the basic approach.)

The rough usage in a component is:

```
const closedPromise = dispatch(showDialog("TestDialog", {dialogNumber : counter});
const result = await closedPromise
// do something with the result
```

That way you can write the "on confirm" logic write there in the place that asked for the dialog to be shown in the first place.

Comment: I'm just curious what is wrong with the traditional approach - implement onClose and passing callback? UI logic stays in UI, you don't pollute your app logic and app state with that + testability is way better than this. you are not dependent on thunk and your logic is not running on every single redux cycle.

Comment: The assumption in my initial posts is that you want to "remotely pass props" into the component, per my example dispatch. In that case, the props get put into the Redux store, and a "dialog manager" component reads them from the store and renders the actual modal. Because of that, you can't legally pass a function as a prop to the dialog, since functions are not allowed in the Redux store. So, we have to work around that constraint somehow.

Comment: @markerikson this is IMO antipattern where you break reusability just by coupling it with your store. what is wrong just with passing the props from the parent component which can and should be connected to the store in this case? In my opinion, this answer (even though it directly responds to question) is misleading.

Comment: The answer I provided is entirely valid for the question being asked. There's multiple ways to handle modals in a React (+Redux) app. The approach I've used in a couple apps was driving all modal display via a single root `<ModalParent>` component, and letting any part of the app trigger showing a modal via dispatching an action. Whether you like that approach is up to you, but this is a valid potential approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you markerikson for providing an answer. This inspired me to create a solution with thunks. Please give me some feedback here :)
I will be using hooks and @reduxjs/toolkit in my example.

This is the state of my `ConfirmationModal` reducer:

```
export interface confirmationModalState {
  isOpened: boolean;
  isConfirmed: boolean;
  isCancelled: boolean;
}

export const initialConfirmationModalState: confirmationModalState = {
  isOpened: false,
  isConfirmed: false,
  isCancelled: false,
};
```

This is the slice (a combination of the reducer and actions):

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { initialConfirmationModalState } from './state';

const confirmationModalSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'controls/confirmationModal',
  initialState: initialConfirmationModalState,
  reducers: {
    open: state => {
      state.isOpened = true;
      state.isConfirmed = false;
      state.isCancelled = false;
    },
    confirm: state => {
      state.isConfirmed = true;
      state.isOpened = false;
    },
    cancel: state => {
      state.isCancelled = true;
      state.isOpened = false;
    },
  },
});

export const confirmationModalActions = confirmationModalSlice.actions;

export default confirmationModalSlice;
```

This is the thunk action for it:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import ThunkApiConfig from '../../../types/ThunkApiConfig';
import { AppState } from '../../reducers';
import { confirmationModalActions } from './slice';

const confirmationModalThunkActions = {
  open: createAsyncThunk<boolean, void, ThunkApiConfig>(
    'controls/confirmationModal',
    async (_, { extra, dispatch }) => {
      const store = extra.store;

      dispatch(confirmationModalActions.open());

      return await new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
        store.subscribe(() => {
          const state: AppState = store.getState();
          if (state.controls.confirmationModal.isConfirmed) {
            resolve(true);
          }
          if (state.controls.confirmationModal.isCancelled) {
            resolve(false);
          }
        });
      });
    },
  ),
};

export default confirmationModalThunkActions;
```

You can notice it uses `extra.store` to perform the `subscribe`. We need to provide it when creating a store:

```
import combinedReducers from './reducers';
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { ThunkExtraArguments } from '../types/ThunkExtraArguments';

function createStore() {
  const thunkExtraArguments = {} as ThunkExtraArguments;

  const customizedMiddleware = getDefaultMiddleware({
    thunk: {
      extraArgument: thunkExtraArguments,
    },
  });

  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: combinedReducers,
    middleware: customizedMiddleware,
  });
  
  thunkExtraArguments.store = store;

  return store;
}

export default createStore();
```

Now, let's create a hook that allows us to dispatch all of the above actions:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { AppState } from '../../../reducers';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import confirmationModalThunkActions from '../thunk';
import { confirmationModalActions } from '../slice';
import { AppDispatch } from '../../../../index';

export function useConfirmationModalState() {
  const dispatch: AppDispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isOpened } = useSelector((state: AppState) => ({
    isOpened: state.controls.confirmationModal.isOpened,
  }));

  const open = useCallback(() => {
    return dispatch(confirmationModalThunkActions.open());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const confirm = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(confirmationModalActions.confirm());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const cancel = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(confirmationModalActions.cancel());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return {
    open,
    confirm,
    cancel,
    isOpened,
  };
}
```

(don't forget to attach `confirm` and `cancel` to the buttons in your modal)

And that's it! We can now dispatch our confirmation modal:

```
export function usePostControls() {
  const { deleteCurrentPost } = usePostsManagement();
  const { open } = useConfirmationModalState();

  const handleDelete = async () => {
    const { payload: isConfirmed } = await open();

    if (isConfirmed) {
      deleteCurrentPost();
    }
  };

  return {
    handleDelete,
  };
}
```

Comment: Looks like it might be doable. Biggest thing I see is that you're never unsubscribing from the store in there, and you really need to make sure you do that. Also, passing the store itself in as the "extra argument" is kinda sketchy :)  surprised it works, tbh.  Personally I'd just go ahead and write a custom middleware for this kind of use case.

Comment: sorry man, this hurts my eyes. for such a simple thing as generic modal with react you need two other libraries, you are polluting the application state with UI logic (what if your app is using different modals in different platforms?), and writing unit test for this must be an utter pain in the back since you are throwing promises around like a politician.

Comment: @webduvet What other solution with Redux would you suggest to create generic confirmation modals? I wrote unit tests for the proposed solution and it was straightforward.

Comment: I assume it should be a reusable component so it should be fully independent of your application setup. I would assume a simple API where you pass handlers which are just simple callbacks. checkout how material-UI does it.